# Ember.js input, escaped values

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In such case:

```
{{input
value=value disabled=disabled
type='text' required='required'
}}
```

When `value='"SomeName"'`

User sees `&quot;SomeName&quot;`

How to avoid this behavior?

An example:
https://ember-twiddle.com/a9b2be7cd1029a79fa077bcbd127e9ab

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit more, or provide a sample [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com)? The problem is unclear.

Comment: @locks sorry, stackoverflow escaped important details, I've edited the post.

Comment: I see `"SomeName"` not `&quot;`. Can you create ember twiddle to demo it?

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/a9b2be7cd1029a79fa077bcbd127e9ab

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format inline code with backticks so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!